# Расследование ссылки в Django

Tags: python, django

Разбираю пример магазина (код чужой), мне нужно докопаться до ссылки http://www.mysite.ru/akcii и разобратсья, почему эта ссылка работает как с **'/'** в конце, так и без **'/'**. Если бы я нашел эту ссылку в регулярках urls.py , то эта проблема решалась бы наличием **'$'**, но ссылки там нет, берется с какого-то другого места, сначала я посмотрел в шаблоны, эта ссылка растет из:

> ```
> <div class="catalog-title catalog-drop-promo"><a
>                     href="{{ cached_tree.29.url }}">{{
> cached_tree.29.item.title }}</a></div>
> ```

Убедившись в том, что это нужная ссылка, далее нашел функцию в файле `context_processors.py`:

```
def cached_tree(request):
    return {'cached_tree': request.cached_tree}
```

На этом мои поиски ссылки закончились, т.к. я в тупике, откуда она генерится и берется, может, кто-нибудь подскажет?

Comment: Почти наверняка у вас в urls.py есть паттерн, который жрет все ссылки, включая эту. Вам нужно смотреть на его вьюху и там по-любому будет код, который отбрасывает слеши и сравнивает без них.

Comment: Если ничего такого в urls не найдете, гляньте список подключенных middleware. Там может быть джанговская FlatpageFallbackMiddleware либо какая либо кастомная middleware которая отлавливает 404 и пытается вместо них выдать страницу.

Comment: Капнул чуть глубже в middleware, да, там кастомный класс: 

    class MiddlewareCachedTree(object):
        def process_request(self, request):
            request.cached_tree = CacheTree(Category.tree_get(), request.path)

Понятно теперь, откуда беруться ссылки, из бд Category, но почему в urls нет явных признаков регулярок для пропуска таких ссылок, они же не должны работать, может, в Django есть еще какие-то способы?

Comment: Вообщем всем спасибо, всё крутилось вокруг кастомным классов в middleware, проблема решена.

Comment: @AlexeyAl Если вы решили данный вопрос, пожалуйста напишите для него ответ отдельным сообщением. Он будет помечен как решенный и это может помочь большему числу людей.